# How to "cache" persistent settings in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

i'm developing an asp.net application. In my database i've a "classic" mono-record settings table. 
Each time i need a setting, i write some code like this

```
if ReturnSetting("my_setting") = value then
'do something
else
'do others
end if
```

In 'ReturnSetting' i open a connection, get the setting value and return it. 
This is not efficient (open connection, datareader etc.)

How can i optimize this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write the call to the function on the Global.asax file in the application start event to load this data once from the database and put the result in an application  object and update your "ReturnSetting" function to check for the application object and this will optimize your code so that the database call is done once.

N.B. This solution will work effectively if this is global web site settings but if it is a user setting so you have to use the Session Start event in the global.asax and the session to store the data in.

Answer (score 1):

you could write a variable and fill them only on the first request. The next requests will return the already filled variable.

```
public static class Settings
{
    internal static Dictionary<string, object> _settingsCache = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    internal static Mutex _mutex = new Mutex();

    public static object Get(string key)
    {
        _mutex.WaitOne();
        if (_settingsCache[key] == null)
        {
            // add to the cache 
            _settingsCache.Add(key, NEW_DATA)
        }
        _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        return _settingsCache[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: static variable? at which level ? into the form ? into global.asax ? where ?

Comment: What if two requests come simultaneously, pass the check _settingsCache[key] == null and will try to retrieve data from database and save it to dictionary :) ?

Comment: you can prevent that using a Mutex (System.Threading). I changed my answer again

Comment: Better just change _settingsCache.Add(key, NEW_DATA) to _settingsCache[key] = NEW_DATA. And even better to use Cache class.

Comment: The Mutex needs to be static too.